# Specifying data directory for a specific database in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, datadirectory

I have a mysql database with 4 different databases. 1 of the databases has a lot of read/write activity that would benefit from being run on ramdisk. Due to the nature of the data layout and types of reads needed, memcached is not an effective option here. Therefore, I would like to run one of the databases in a ramdisk (data persistence is not an issue here).

The question: Is there anyway to set the data directory for just one table in a mysql database? I want 3 of the databases to have a data directory on my harddrive, and the other one pointed towards a directory in a ramdisk. If not, how could I install two instances of mysql on the same server (I am using Ubuntu).

Btw: I am aware of the MEMORY engine but that barely improve performance (doesn't seem to truly be running in memory).

EDIT:

I accidentally asked to specify the data directory for a table. What I actually meant was to ask how to specify the data directory for a 1 out of 4 databases in a mysql installation. The post has been updated to reflect this correction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For MyISAM tables, you can just provide a `DATA DIRECTORY` & `INDEX DIRECTORY` clause in your [`CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) statement (if you partition your table, you'll have to set it per partition I believe).

```
$ mkdir /tmp/datadir
$ sudo chown mysql:mysql /tmp/datadir/
$ mysql
mysql> use test;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> create table otherlocation (id int) ENGINE=MyISAM, DATA DIRECTORY='/tmp/datadir', INDEX DIRECTORY='/tmp/datadir';

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
mysql> Bye
$ ls -lah /tmp/datadir/
total 496K
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql 4.0K Oct 18 00:57 .
drwxrwxrwt 32 root  root  484K Oct 18 00:55 ..
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql    0 Oct 18 00:57 otherlocation.MYD
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1.0K Oct 18 00:57 otherlocation.MYI
```

Comment: Would you be able to show me what the proper query would look like? Everytime I try it, it says no database selected.

Comment: Added the command line example with requirements (existing dir, proper ownership, proper ENGINE)

Comment: How complete is this? Is it like a `foo.c`/`foo.h` file where you can drag and drop? Can I make an `nfs` share of `/tmp/datadir` and share across any Linux machine or are there common files stored somewhere else specific to that single machine only?

Comment: @puk: drag & drop? Perhaps when the database is off, but I wouldn't rely on it (I rarely use MyISAM anymore as there usually are better alternatives like innodb, tokudb, et al.). While you can technically (AFAIK) have de data dir on any directory, including nfs mounts (smb mounts, ssh mounts, etc.), you cannot run multiple mysql instances with that same datadir, and the performance would be horrible. What is this for? Having a replica is better served with replication, seperating storage & cpu is better served with MySQL Cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the files to the ramdisk and create symlink to their original location.